# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?" in both JSON.parse() and $.parseJSON()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have no idea why I am getting this and I have spent over a day trying to mess with the code. Now the simplest I can get is this (Trying to build a javascript array with an escaped string coming from a database):

```
vat test = '["<script>var bob = \\"This is ok\\"</script>", "<script>search.replace(/!|\\\?)/g, \\"\\")</script>"]';
```

So far, so good.

Then this breaks and returns the error:

```
JSON.parse(test);
```

To give an idea, the original 2 array items were this:

```
<script>var bob = "This is ok"</script>
<script>search.replace(/!|\?)/g, "")</script>
```

All the codes of any kind that were entered in the database have always worked, except now, because of that question mark from a user-entered line in my CMS. If I remove it or replace the question mark by anything else, it works.

I cannot change the regex so to make it work any other way, I am not the one who entered this. Plus this is a simplified version of a whole script, I just narrowed it to the question mark.

I also looked online if the question mark had a special meaning for json, did not find anything.

I wish I could have sent a fiddle instead of just code, but jsfiddle doesn't let me add the  tag in the javascript window.

Comment: I believe it is the \\\ that might be causing trouble, though, not the question mark

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Seems like an XY problem...

Comment: I do have this error now on NuxtJs, so weird it is located on node_modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSON.parse('["<script>var bob = \\"This is ok\\"</script>", "<script>search.replace(/!|\\\?)/g, \\"\\")</script>"]')
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
```

There are two unescapes going on here, so you need an extra `\` before the `?`

```
JSON.parse('["<script>var bob = \\"This is ok\\"</script>", "<script>search.replace(/!|\\\\?)/g, \\"\\")</script>"]')
["<script>var bob = "This is ok"</script>", "<script>search.replace(/!|\?)/g, "")</script>"]
```

Comment: Damn! Because I was trying to fix it, I did not try to edit the problem at the source! Almost there, I cannot edit the string entered by the user though, neither can I change how it is escaped in the database. I can however add an extra "replace" like such: test.replace('\\\', '\\\\'). But I need to escape the backslashes I'm replacing as well, so I tried test.replace('\\\\\\', '\\\\') and test.replace('\\\\\\', '\\\\\\\\') but neither work. This is ugly I know, but I'm close, thanks to you!